# delta lake in databricks - a consistent "view" of just the last half hour of a stream

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, delta-lake

I have consisently updated table from spark structured streaming (kafka source)
Written like this (in eachBatch)

```py
parsedDf \
        .select("somefield", "anotherField",'partition', 'offset') \
        .write \
        .format("delta") \
        .mode("append") \
        .option("mergeSchema", "true") \
        .save(f"/mnt/defaultDatalake/{append_table_name}")
```

I need to keep a fast view on this table for "items inserted in the last half hour"
How can this be achieved?
I can have a readStream from this table, but what I'm missing is how keep just the "tail" of the stream there

Databricks 7.5 spark 3.

Comment: sorry got that wrong. point is do you have timestamp in the data for a where clause?

Comment: rolling half hr window?

Comment: nothing special if a timestamp for querying is there against latest version.

Comment: I don't want to query each time, I want sort of a materialized view / or a real table which constantly updates from this table but contains a window of the data (let's say the last half hour)

Comment: Then you need to make that clear in the question - do you not think, as I suspected as much. I am wondering if that is possible. I do not think so.

Answer (score 0):

Given that Delta lake does not have materalized views and that Delta Lake time-travel is not relevant as you want the most current data:

- You can load the data and include a key that does not need to be looked up whilst inserting.
- Pre-populate a time dimension for joining with your data. See it as a dimension with a grain of a minute.
- Join the data with this dimension, relying on dynamic file pruning. Thus you need to query per minute every 30 minutes with rolling window and set those values in the query.
- See [https://databricks.com/blog/2020/04/30/faster-sql-queries-on-delta-lake-with-dynamic-file-pruning.html#:~:text=Dynamic%20File%20Pruning%20(DFP)%2C%20a%20new%20feature%20now%20enabled,queries%20on%20non%2Dpartitioned%20tables](https://databricks.com/blog/2020/04/30/faster-sql-queries-on-delta-lake-with-dynamic-file-pruning.html#:%7E:text=Dynamic%20File%20Pruning%20(DFP)%2C%20a%20new%20feature%20now%20enabled,queries%20on%20non%2Dpartitioned%20tables).

Comment: I might be misunderstanding you , but wouldn't this suggestion just show the "whole" table as it was in a certain version/timestamp? I don't want the whole tables just events created in the last half hour (the tail of the append only log)